# jqGrid. How to show a seperate page when the user click add button?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am very novice when it comes to MVC, jQuery and jqGrid.  I am stuck for the last two days to find a solution on how to redirect to a another page when the user clicks the add button.  I also need to do the same on edit button but before doing that I need to call a javascript function to check whether the requested row can be edited or not.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Here is the code I used to create the jqGrid

```
var jqDataUrl = "Account/LoadBaseData";
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Set up the jquery grid
            $("#ListTable").jqGrid({
                // Ajax related configurations
                url: jqDataUrl,
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: "POST",
                // Specify the column names
                colNames: ["Bank","Account No","Account Name"],
                // Configure the columns
                colModel: [ { name: "BankReference", index: "BankReference", width: 40, align: "left"}, { name: "AccountNo", index: "AccountNo", width: 40, align: "left"}, { name: "AccountName", index: "AccountName", width: 40, align: "left"}],
                // Grid total width and height
                width: 850,
                height: 400,
                // Paging
                toppager: true,
                pager: $("#ListTablePager"),
                rowNum: 14,
                viewrecords: true, // Specify if "total number of records" is displayed
                // Grid caption
                caption: "BankAccount List",
                editurl: "/GridDemo/GridSave",
            }).navGrid("#ListTablePager",
            { refresh: true, add: true, edit: true, del: true},
                { }, // settings for edit
                {}, // settings for add
                {}, // settings for delete
                {sopt: ["cn"]}  
            );


        });
```

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Please provide more details and code samples. Redirect might be done with:

$('#btn').click(function() {
window.location.href = 'newurl.html';
return false;
});

Comment: $('#btn').click(function() { window.location.href = 'newurl.html'; return false; }); looks a good solution.  But how will I know what is the name of the button for the add / edit button that are created dynamically?

Comment: Could you provide a working example on jsfiddle? Edit / add buttons must have css classes to bind to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The add, edit buttons that comes with jqgrid is used for add/edit records through inline/form. In your case you want to do a redirect on click of the add/edit button based upon some condition, so I would suggest to use custom buttons and that's quite easy.

```
$("#ListTable").jqGrid({
  ...
})
.navGrid("#ListTablePager", {edit:false, add:false, del:false,search:false })
.navButtonAdd("#ListTablePager", { // custom add button
   caption:"Add",  
   buttonicon:"ui-icon-add", 
   onClickButton: function(){ 
     var grid = $("#grid_name"); // ur jqgrid
     var rowid = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'); // get the selected rowid

     // u can get the cell value of the row by 
     // grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'rowName');

     if(your condition)
        window.location = ...
   }, 
   position:"last"
})
.navButtonAdd('#ListTablePager',{ // custom edit button
   caption:"Edit", 
   buttonicon:"ui-icon-edit", 
   onClickButton: function(){ 
      ...
   }, 
   position:"last"
});
```

I don't understand what you mean by *requested row can be edited or not* you can get the current selected row inside the `onClickButton` event by

```
var grid = $("#grid_name");

var rowid = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
```

You can get a particular cell value of the selected row by,

```
grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'rowName');
```

So based upon this you can easily frame your condition and set the window.location to do the redirect.

Comment: Thankx a million.. That solved my problem.. Great work.. Thank you once again